# How to get search results in order of relevance in mysql?

Tags: mysql, search

I am trying to search a table for records according to relevance with search keywords.

My query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM downloads
WHERE (
    (name LIKE '%Micky Mobile%')
    OR (name LIKE '%Micky%' OR name LIKE '%Mobile%')
    OR (name LIKE '%Micky%')
    OR (name LIKE '%Mobile%')
) AND app='1'
```

This works fine but problem is:

What I want from this query is the row that has name "Hello Micky Mobile T" at 1st place.

Row having name "Hello Micky T Mobile" at 2nd place.

Row having "Hello Micky T" at 3rd place.

Row having "Hello Mobile T" at 4th place.

But above query gives results in ASC order by id(Auto incremented field).

Union solves my problem but it takes much more time that it should (I suppose).
There must be an other way.

Comment: To be more precise, it doesn't return the results in ASC order by id, but rather returns the results in their _default_ order, which, in MySQL, I believe represents insert-order.  In many cases that will be the same as ASC order by the auto-inc id, but this is _not_ guaranteed, and should not be relied on. I mention this just as a side note, since I know this isn't the real point of your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In my case I am getting results in ASC order by ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you're searching for Micky and Mobile twice.

Secondly, I believe MySQL has some Full-Text Search possibilities that have relevance options built-in to them:
[MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)

Comment: I am using a Union for now. "Micky" and "Mobile" are searched twice because they need to be  displayed in order by "relevancy". There is a php code after this query to filter duplicate results.
I know its messy.. :p
I checked "Full Text Search". Its almost same what I am searching with few exceptions like It gives weightage to something else than I need.
For Eg: {SELECT name FROM downloads WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('micky mobile');} returns "Micky T Micky" at first place and "Micky Mobile" at 2nd. 
It gives priority to one word repeated twice instead of two words repeated once.